# X11 app launching seemingly randomly

Tags: macos, dock, x11

Since a month or two, I started seeing an X11 icon in my dock.
Killing it does not kill any other app.

Is there any way to see what process launches this app?

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to open Activity Monitor, and check the process ID (PID) of running programs that are immediately before and after the X11 process.